# Making a method in a class that doesn't need to be called by an object of said class

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm not really sure how to describe this question well, so apologies if this is hard to understand:

Just as a practice (I'm still quite new to C#) I wanted to make an class, Point, that worked like points on a coordinate grid. I have this so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Point_Class
{
    class Point
    {
        private int x, y;
        public Point() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Default Constructor Loaded.");
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
        }
        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public string Equation(Point p1, Point p2)
        {

        }
    }

    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point x,y;
            x = new Point(2, 2);
            y = new Point(5, 6);
            x.DistanceTo(y);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, my question is this: Is there a way to run the Equation (function or method, unsure of terms) like this

```
Equation(Point x, Point y);
```

or does it have to be different?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it static:

```
class Point
{
    public static string Equation(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Now you can call it with

```
var result = Point.Equation(x, y);
```

Comment: Also referred to as the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).